# matplotlib 3D heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

How to use pcolormesh to plot a heatmap? I have three lists of equal size, X, Y and Z. When I do

```
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
```

I get "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"
and when I do

```
plt.pcolormesh(np.array(zip(X, Y)), Z)
```

I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at the documentation for [pcolor](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) to see the requirements for the input arguments to pcolormesh. x, y and c can't be lists of numbers, they have be lists of lists or two dimensional numpy arrays. You need two dimensional arrays because pcolor and pcolormesh draw a quadrilateral for each value of c with corners defined in x and y. The x and y values that correspond to a particular value in c are determined by their location in the array.

From the documentation:

"X and Y, if given, specify the (x, y) coordinates of the colored quadrilaterals; the quadrilateral for C[i,j] has corners at:

(X[i,   j],   Y[i,   j]),
(X[i,   j+1], Y[i,   j+1]),
(X[i+1, j],   Y[i+1, j]),
(X[i+1, j+1], Y[i+1, j+1])."

To change your x and y lists into two dimensional numpy arrays you can use [meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,11)
y = np.arange(0,11)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x,y)
c = np.random.rand(10,10)

plt.pcolormesh(xv,yv,c)

plt.show()
```

[image: pcolormesh example]